# Can't assign structure to pointer of structure

Tags: c++, data-structures

So i have this simple data structure and I want to print all characters from it, but I can't assign n to n.next. I programmed in java a bit, and this kind of things worked. What is wrong with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    char c;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

typedef struct node NODE;

void printnode(NODE n){
    while(n.next){
        cout << n.c;
        n=n.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointers are completely separate types that hold addresses. They are not compatible with the type they point to at all.

Comment: what do you mean by "I can't assign"? what is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
void printnode(NODE* n){
  while(n->next){
    cout << n->c;
    n=n->next;
  }
}
```

It uses a pointer to access `NODE`.

In your version, you are are trying to assign a pointer to a non-pointer type:

```
void printnode(NODE n){    
  ...
  n = n.next; // error: n.next is of type NODE*, but n is a non-pointer NODE
```

Answer (score 5):

`n` is `NODE` which is `struct node` but `n.next` is `struct node *` so you can't assigne `n.next` to `n`.

To makes it works you can change you're functions argument to :

```
void printnode(NODE *n) {
    while (n->next != NULL) {
        cout << n->c;
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

Note that we use the `->` operator to access the members of a struct pointed to with a pointer.

Comment: n.next should be n->next

Comment: @PhilippClaßen Tanks!

Answer (score 2):

To use a data pointed by a pointer (to dereference a pointer)

```
node* p;
```

you have to type:

```
p->next;
```

This is the correct version of your code:

```
void printnode( NODE *n) {
    while ( n->next != NULL) {
        cout << n->c;
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet looks a lot like C rather than C++. 
Here's how you get your code to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    char c;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

typedef struct node NODE;

void printnode(NODE* n){
    while(n->next){
        cout << n->c;
        n=n->next;
    }
}
```

...and here's what you really want, which does exactly the same thing with optimal efficiency and correctness.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <forward_list>

using namespace std;

using mylist_t = std::forward_list<char>;

void printList(const mylist_t& list){
    for(const auto& c : list) {
        cout << c;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually it's not what I want, cause it's for my class. We're learning data structures. But thanks anyway